# How do I determine the bias of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, probability

Let's say I have an algorithm that is supposed to represent a coin flip. How do I determine the bias of this coin? Specifically, I have written the algorithm in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsumners/KU68f/).

The fiddle runs a series of 20 tests. Each test flips the coin 100 times and tallies the results. At the end of the series it reports `Heads/Tails` for the total number of flips across all tests. This result seems to be approaching 1 (from both sides), but I have not done any rigorous testing of this.

Note, this is not homework. This is purely a personal interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't come up with a way to guarantee detecting a bias, but you can determine it to a certain degree of certainty (say 95%). What you do is test *n* times and count how many times you get heads, call this variable *h*.

Then if *h* / *n* < 0.5 - 1.96 * sqrt(0.25 / *n*) then the coin is biased towards tails (with a 95% probability) and if *h* / *n* > 0.5 + 1.96 * sqrt(0.25 / *n*) then the coin is biased towards heads.

This decision is based on something called *normal approximation to a binomial distribution*, you can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval

Answer (score 1):

[George Marsaglia Diehard Tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests)

if you consider your Head/Tail as generating 0 1 bits. Using them you can generate random numbers and test their randomness